# Split an amount into 2 random groups by Gauss bell

Tags: c#, algorithm, random, probability

Let's suppose I've 100 items and I need to split them into two groups.

Options can be:

1. Divide by 2, so I get exactly 50 and 50
2. Select a random number between 1 and 100 and then separate that amount from the rest.

In option 2, 1 item has the same probability than 50 items (1/100)
But in the reality, I imagine a Gauss bell where for e.g., 50 has the most probability, 49 and 48 the less, 47 and 46 more less, and so far.

Question:

**How can simulate that "random with probability" selection?

Is there any function to do this in .NET 6?**

By the way I'm working in C# but I think I can handle the lines, so that's why I don't write code here, but not the logic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Box–Muller transform? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box–Muller_transform

Comment: I think can be related, but I can't modify the code in order to get a number between 1 and 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your option 2 by iterating through the set of items and allocating each one to set 1 or set 2 with probability p = 0.5. The resulting sets have a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), B(n=100, p=0.5), which will give a discrete approximation to the bell-shaped normal distribution. The actual results will vary, but there's a low likelihood of the set counts varying from 50 by more than 10, which corresponds to 2 standard deviations with that parameterization.

I'm not a C# user so I won't attempt to fake it in your preferred language, but it's pretty straightforward. Since Python is widely used and is pseudocode-like, here's the algorithm in that language:

```python
import random

# create an array with the numbers 1 to 100
values = [i for i in range(1, 101)]

# repeat the following set of operations 10 times...
for replication in range(10):
    # create two empty arrays
    set1 = []
    set2 = []

    # Note: random.random() produces float values in the range [0.0, 1.0),
    # the probability of getting a value < 0.5 is 1/2

    # iterate through each of the values from the array created above
    for value in values:
        if random.random() < 0.5:  # with probability 1/2
            set1.append(value)     # the value goes in the first set
        else:
            set2.append(value)     # otherwise it goes in the second set

    # once all values have been allocated, count how
    # many are in each set and print the results
    print(len(set1), " : ", len(set2))
```

which produces 10 splits such as:

```text
49  :  51
48  :  52
47  :  53
59  :  41
39  :  61
50  :  50
43  :  57
54  :  46
50  :  50
60  :  40
```

If you want to favor one set or the other, adjust the p-value for the allocations. By simply changing the conditional to

```python
if random.random() < 0.7:
```

you'll get results such as:

```text
71  :  29
76  :  24
80  :  20
67  :  33
67  :  33
72  :  28
66  :  34
67  :  33
72  :  28
68  :  32
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I will try to understand and translate this!

Comment: This is so elegant and simple, that I will never ever think it about it, so is very hard (at least to me). A shame only can give you some points, really admire you!

Comment: That's very kind, but I suspect this is foreign to you and it's right up my alley. Besides, I'm a professor so I love sharing stuff like this.

Comment: I would like to be you my proffesor!!! Thanks a lot for your sharing

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing a book about something else not related to maths or software, this is for a simulation of that topic. Would you agree I could quote you? If you want, please write me your name or FW your CV in an email in you don't want to make it public here. Is hola @ leandrobardelli dot com

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Just use whatever you want from this discussion, no quotations or citations needed.